# cloudformation package uploading hash instead of zip

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have a serverless api I'm trying to upload to cloudformation and am having some issues.  According to the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html),

> For example, if your AWS Lambda function source code is in the /home/user/code/lambdafunction/ folder, specify `CodeUri: /home/user/code/lambdafunction` for the AWS::Serverless::Function resource. The command returns a template and replaces the local path with the S3 location: CodeUri: s3://mybucket/lambdafunction.zip.

I'm using a relative path (I've tried an absolute path as well), so I have `CodeUri: ./` instead of `/user/libs/code/functionDirectory/`.  When I package the files, it looks like a hash is being uploaded to S3, but it's not a zip (when I try and download it, my computer doesn't recognize the file type)
[image]
Is this expected?  I was expecting a .zip file to be upload.  Am I completely missing something here?

Thanks for any help.
Walker

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is expected. When you use `CodeUri` the files are archived and stored in S3, it can be extracted with `unzip` command or any other utility.

```
> file 009aebc05d33e5dddf9b9570e7ee45af
009aebc05d33e5dddf9b9570e7ee45af: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

> unzip 009aebc05d33e5dddf9b9570e7ee45af
Archive:  009aebc05d33e5dddf9b9570e7ee45af
replace AWSSDK.SQS.dll? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there something else I can do to have the file uploaded as a named zip file? For example, in the docs, it makes it seem that if the CodeUri `CodeUri: /home/user/code/lambdafunction`, then the uploaded file will be `lambdafunction.zip`. (ie zip file with the name of the directory).  It'd be great to have a named file instead of a hash.